# httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log. Unable to open logs

Tags: apache2, centos

When i start my centOS server. Its through me error like below.

Starting httpd: (20)Not a directory: httpd: could not open error log file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs

Please help me to fix this. Even i checked the permission of logs.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of permission of file. you should set permission for zabbix user.

Comment: Please improve the explanation on this answer. Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.